# Expressão regular para pegar parte de texto

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte texto:

```
17/7/2014 14:58:44

Finalizada

170848546
```

Preciso pegar exatamente o "Finalizada", é PHP, não consigo entender expressões regulares, alguém me da uma luz?

Criei o seguinte:

```
/([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])\n[a-zA-Z]*/
```

Mas não funcionou, lembrando que cada palavra está em uma linha diferente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o padrão que tem é hora > texto > numero, teste esta regex `/[0-9]{2}.*:[[0-6]{2}\s*(.*)\s*[0-9]{1,}/`

#### Demo: https://ideone.com/PmGiuL

Código:

```
$input = '17/7/2014 14:58:44

Finalizada

170848546';


$regex = '/[0-9]{2}.*:[[0-6]{2}\s*(.*)\s*[0-9]{1,}/';
preg_match($regex, $input, $resposta);
echo 'O textto encontrado foi: '.$resposta[1]; // Dá Finalizada
```

Regex explicada:

- `[0-9]{2}` - qualquer numero entre 0 e 9, dois caracteres
- `\/` - uma barra (escapada para não confundir com o sinalizador de fim da regex)
- `.*` - qualquer caracter excepto quebra de linha
- `:` - dois pontos
- `[0-6]{2}` - qualquer numero entre 0 e 6, dois caracteres
- `\s*` - quebra de linha, n vezes
- `(.*)` - aqui o interessante são os parenteses que siginfica **capturar**
- `[0-9]{1,}` - qualquer numero entre 0 e 9, n caracteres

Se esse padrão se repetir muitas vezes pode usar `preg_match_all` em vez de só `preg_match` e aí a variável `$resposta[1]` vai ser uma array com os resultados encontrados.

Comment: Acho que entendi a pergunta pela sua resposta +1, e exclui a minha resposta :p

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era exatamente isso.