# Pegar URL com expressão regular de links

Tags: php, regex

Estou tentando extrair somente a URL caso uma expressão seja validada com a tag `[monitory]`.

A expressão que uso é esta:

```
(?=<a.*\[monitory\].*href=["|'][http:|https:]?[\/\/]).*?["|']>
```

E por exemplo em um link assim:

```
<a [monitory] href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Extrair somente o endereço:

```
http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro vamos ver alguns detalhes na [sua regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343730/112052) (e também sugestões para melhorá-la).

Usar `.*` é sempre tentador, porém "perigoso", já que é uma expressão que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências de *qualquer caractere*". Além disso, o quantificador é [ganancioso](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy), ou seja, ele vai tentar pegar o máximo de caracteres possível.

Isso quer dizer que se sua string tiver dois links na mesma linha, o primeiro será ignorado. Por exemplo, se a string for:

```
<a [monitory] href="http://www.link1.com"><a [monitory] href="http://www.link2.com">
```

Somente o endereço `http://www.link2.com` será considerado, pois o `.*` pega o máximo de caracteres que puder (inclusive todo o trecho do "link1.com"). [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/BVmdh3/1/) esta regex funcionando.

Para cancelar a ganância, coloque um `?` logo depois do `*`:

```
<a.*?\[monitory\].*?href=["|']([http:|https:]?[\/\/]?.*?)["|']>
```

Assim, o `.*` passa a pegar o mínimo necessário, fazendo com que tanto o "link1" quanto o "link2" sejam capturados pela regex. [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/BVmdh3/2/) a diferença.

---

Outro detalhe é que `["|']` é uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), ou seja, ela aceita todos os caracteres que estão nos colchetes. Portanto esta expressão significa o caractere `"` **ou** o caractere `|` **ou** o caractere `'`. Isso quer dizer que a string poderia ter `|` no lugar das aspas:

```
<a [monitory] href=|http://www.teste.com|>
```

E ainda sim a regex aceitaria, [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/k8SYnY/1/).

Se quiser que tenha apenas `"` ou `'`, remova o `|` dos colchetes: `["']`.

De modo análogo, `[\/\/]` significa o caractere `/` **ou** o caractere `/` (ou seja, é redundante ter duas vezes o mesmo caractere dentro dos colchetes - e em algumas linguagens isso até dá erro). Isso faz com que a regex aceite apenas uma barra na URL (`http:/www.teste.com`), [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/k8SYnY/2/) um exemplo.

Se quer duas ocorrências de `/`, elimine os colchetes.

O trecho `[http:|https:]?` também deve ser retirado dos colchetes, pelos motivos já explicados acima. Na verdade a regex só funciona porque tanto este trecho quanto o `[\/\/]` possuem um `?` logo depois, o que os torna opcionais, e depois deles tem um `.*?`, que corresponde a quaisquer caracteres. Para entender melhor, coloque parênteses em volta de cada um deles e [veja o trecho que cada um captura](https://regex101.com/r/BVmdh3/3/).

Para aceitar http ou https, basta fazer `https?`: o trecho `s?` torna a letra `s` opcional. Então a regex ficaria:

```
<a.*?\[monitory\].*?href=["'](https?:\/\/.*?)["']>
```

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/k8SYnY/5/) ela funcionando.

---

Ah sim, esta regex só funciona se `[monitory]` estiver antes de `href`, e se logo depois das aspas que fecham o `href` não tiver nenhum espaço. Dá para melhorar um pouco mais, trocando `.*?` por `\s+` (uma ou mais ocorrências de espaços) e no final, antes de fechar a tag, colocar `\s*` (pois pode ter zero ou mais espaços antes do `>`):

```
<a\s+\[monitory\]\s+href=["'](https?:\/\/.*?)["']\s*>
```

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/k8SYnY/7/) esta regex funcionando.

---

Repare que isso não tem fim, pois tags HTML são mais complexas do que parecem. Se você garante que suas strings sempre têm este formato e não há mais variações, a regex resolve. Mas se tiver mais casos (`href` antes de `monitory`, outros atributos, URL tem protocolos como ftp, gopher, mailto, ou é simplesmente `localhost`, etc), você terá que atualizar a regex.

O uso de `.*` faz com que sejam aceitas URLs inválidas, como `http:///#@@#@#@` ou até mesmo `http://` ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/k8SYnY/8/)). Se quiser mesmo validar qualquer URL, acabará com [expressões monstruosas como esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/341054/112052), e aí começa a não valer a pena usar algo tão complicado.

Regex, apesar de ser muito legal, [não é a melhor ferramenta para parsing e manipulação de HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Talvez seja o caso de tentar [ferramentas mais adequadas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641).

---

<sup>Entendo que a [sua regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343730/112052) tenha funcionado, mas o problema de regex não é só fazer ela funcionar para os casos válidos, é fazê-la também **não** funcionar para os casos inválidos.</sup>

Comment: Nossa bem explicado. Vou usar esta expressão para monitorar os links acessados fazendo um redirecionamento depois. Obrigado

Comment: Só complementando, isso em emails marketing.

Answer (score 2):

Olhando em outra pegunta feita no stackoverlow entendi uma coisa.

O ( parênteses serve para capturar então eu modifiquei minha expressão para:

```
<a.*\[monitory\].*href=["|']([http:|https:]?[\/\/]?.*?)["|']>
```

E agora deu certo.

A outra pergunta encontra em: [Expressão regular para pegar parte de texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25859/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-pegar-parte-de-texto)